# Asp core web api controller not working when injecting service

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I am new at using ASP.NET Core. Want to create an api using this new framework, but have some startup issues with dependency injection. It should be quite easy, but for somehow when using DI, I get an internal server error 500 when calling the controller from postman.

**Controller:**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SomethingController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISomethingService _somethingService;

    public SomethingController(ISomethingService somethingService)
    {
        _somethingService = somethingService;
    }

    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public int Get()
    {
        return _somethingService.status();
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

**Service with interface**

```
public interface ISomethingService
{
    int status();
}

public class SomethingService : ISomethingService
{
    SomethingService()
    {
    }

    public int status()
    {
        var number = 3;
        return number;
    }
}
```

**Startup class**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();

        // Add application services
        services.AddTransient<ISomethingService, SomethingService>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

As you see, I have already registered the service, so why does it not work as intended?

Also, Have tried to remove the injectiton from the controller, then the controller works fine.

Comment: Maybe its about addign mvc before service in ConigurationServices?

Comment: I would register it as Scoped not Transient, and I would register it before the call to services.AddMvc though not sure that matters

Comment: Does not matter if I have the call over the service.AddMVC, also I get same error if it's an service.AddScoped<>

Comment: Did you get some error details?

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the error message. You might be able to find it in the system log or failing that, you can call the API (with a browser or a test harness) to see the real error message.

Comment: only the 500 internal service error in postman.

Comment: @Mikkel - That is what I am saying, you need to call it outside of postman to get the real error message.

Comment: If it what that easy I would have thrown in the prober error message, Have tried in chrome, but only getting "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error" in log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `SomethingService` constructor is `private`.  Make it `public` so DI can create one.

Comment: Or simply delete this contsructor.